# Dividing a number up into 'equal' whole numbers

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to come up with a formula to divide a number up into a number of parts - where each part is a whole number, and the parts are as 'equal' as possible. I want to provide the number and desired parts, and get the output - e.g.:

- For 18, (3 parts) it would be: `6, 6, 6`
- For 16 (3 parts) it would be: `6, 5, 5`
- For 34 (4 parts) it would be `9, 9, 8, 8`

and so on...

Can anyone give me any pointers as to how to achieve this?

Comment: How do you define how many parts given number should be divided into? E.g. 34 can be 17 and 17 instead.

Comment: I guess desired parts will need to be specified, otherwise it will be a shambles ;)

Comment: Yes, the 2 'inputs' are the number, and the desired parts. Will update for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

=IF(AND(MOD($D$36,$D$37)>F36,$D$37>F36),ROUNDDOWN($D$36/$D$37,0)+1,IF($D$37>F36,ROUNDDOWN($D$36/$D$37,0),""))

I put the number to be divided into D36, parts into D37,and a count going from 0-100 into F36:DB36, 100 was arbitrary, it's just the cap of your parts.

Put the formula below the count and drag it over.

Here it is without the references:

=IF(AND(MOD(Number,Part)>Counter,Part>Counter),ROUNDDOWN(Number/Part,0)+1,IF(Part>Counter,ROUNDDOWN(Number/Part,0),""))

Comment: Essentially it reads as, "If the remainder after the number is divided is greater than the counter, and there are more parts than the counter, then divide the number by the parts, rounding down and add one.
Otherwise, if the parts are still greater than the counter, then divide the number by the parts and round down.
Otherwise, remain blank."

Comment: I should mention, the counter starts at 0, not 1.

Comment: Many thanks! This makes perfect sense - I just had no idea how to say it in Excel! One minor point, the count needs to be 0-100 (your F36:DB36 comment clued me in to why it didn't work at first...)