# Divide a whole number up into specific number of parts, which are whole numbers & as close to equals as possible

Tags: excel-formula

On an Excel spreadsheet, I have a dollar figure of $1,569,230 in cell A2 (which will always be a whole number) and the number 12 in cell A3, representing the number of parts to divide A2 into (this number may vary, such as 4 or 10). I need whole numbers as close to equal as possible to fill in cells C2-N2. What **Excel** formula can I use to accomplish this?

**Need largest results populate first, then smallest**

Tried below solution, but it does not work. And it does not allow me to comment there to get clarification, as I am new to platform. [Dividing a number up into 'equal' whole numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59708025/dividing-a-number-up-into-equal-whole-numbers)

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQawV.png)

Comment: The division formula is `D / d = Q + R` (Dividend, divisor, Quotient, Remainder). Reworking, you know `D` and `d` for a given input, you can take `FLOOR(D / d)` to determine what `Q` is. At that point, `R = (D / D) - Q`, which is your decimal part. `R * d` would be the whole-dollar amount left, which is neatly going to be from 0 up to (but excluding) `d`. So you need to make `R * d` columns with +1 extra to spread the remainder out whilst keeping whole numbers. (If `C` is column 3, then anything past column (R*d) + 3 wouldn't get the +1. There are formulas for column index).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit there was a bug in my previous reply and I decided to have a different (simpler) approach:*

```
=LET(a, INT(A1/B1),
     b, MOD(A1,B1),
IF(SEQUENCE(,B1)<=b,a+1,a))
```

For vertical spill, simply drop the `,` in `SEQUENCE`

*Old approach fixed by Scott Craner* :

```
=LET(a, INT(A1/B1),
     b, MOD(A1,B1),
     c, a+IFERROR(EXPAND(1,,b,1),0), HSTACK(EXPAND(a,,B1-MAX(b,1),a),        c))
```

Comment: a. Tried the horizontal: fails if all of the results are equals (e.g. 16/4=4, gives #VALUE! instead of numbers) 
- Can you think of a way to not have it fail in this scenario, but give numbers?

b. Works if results are not equal (e.g. 17/4=4   4   4   5)
- Can you think of a way to have largest results populate first, then smallest?

Comment: hm, that latest formula gives 4 4 4 4 4 as a result of 16/4, i.e. five fours -- which adds up to 20, not 16...

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "For largest first, change the order of the arrays within (H)STACK"
Can you show me?

Comment: Sorry, ment to post: `=LET(a, INT(A1/B1),      b, MOD(A1,B1),      c, a+IFERROR(EXPAND(1,,b,1),0), HSTACK(c,        EXPAND(a,,B1-b,a)))`

Comment: @P.b try this one: `=LET(a, INT(A1/B1),
     b, MOD(A1,B1),
     c, a+IFERROR(EXPAND(1,,b,1),0),
HSTACK(EXPAND(a,,B1-MAX(b,1),a),
       c))`  It will fix the 16/4 error.

Comment: @ScottCraner I was editing the post already (but that's slow doing that on my mobile). This version should fix it. Your workaround is nice by the way!

Comment: @Scott Craner 
Your formula solved  the issue with 16/4=20
How do you make largest results populate first, then smallest?

Comment: @Cap'nCrunch P.b has fixed that in his answer.

Comment: @Scott Craner - but latest from P.b has 16/4=20 issue in it... I want to be able to mark an answer as resolved -- can you post the formula that has both issues resolved?

Comment: @Cap'nCrunch I updated my answer with a fix back then. Try with the current answer.

Comment: @P.b - tried latest in your answer for horizontal:
20/9=3 3 #N/A #N/A #N/A #N/A #N/A #N/A #N/A

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I decided to not use expand an stack after all debugging, but use SEQUENCE instead. In the end this is much simpler.